# How do I find files in the Finder on my mac that I've created using "touch" in the terminal?

Tags: django, macos, ubuntu, vagrant

I'm restarting the Getting Started with Django tutorial on a newly purchased mac after getting past this step in windows. The tutorial has me working with Vagrant, VM, Venv, and Ubuntu Precise64. I've obviously searched for the names of the files. I've edited the files with vim because I couldn't locate them, but I was always able to easily find the files in windows. I'm sure I'm an idiot, but yes feel free to point that out.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply type

> open .

in the terminal to open the current directory in the finder.
Then you should see all your touched files (not the dot files).

Comment: So I tried that and this is is whay I got back:  `vagrant@precise64:~/microblog$ ls manage.py microblog procfile Procfile requirements.txt subl` `vagrant@precise64:~/microblog$ open .` `Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console` `vagrant@precise64:~/microblog$`

Answer (score 0):

OK looks like I didn't cd into the folder I needed to before I created the venv and ran django-admin startproject. Still found nothing at my vagrant home, was it out on the VM somewhere?    Went thoug h the steps again correctly and everything is fine, so I guess I messed up the simlink somehow???